# Display new message count based on logged in user

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Currently working on a website which is developed in asp and c#. Using signalr I have managed to send new notification each time a new message is received in the database. However the problem I am now having is if say **User1** has one new message and **User2** has 2 new messages. Both of them get displayed for the user. So **User1** will have one new message and so will the **User2**. I am using the code below

```
 [HubMethodName("Notifications")]
    public string SendNotifications()
    {
        string userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "SELECT  NewMessageCount FROM Messages WHERE UserName=@UserName";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                SqlParameter para2 = new SqlParameter(@"UserName", userName);
                command.Parameters.Add(para2);
                command.Notification = null;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    totalNewMessages = Int16.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["NewMessageCount"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationHub>();
        return context.Clients.All.RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Clients.User(userid)`

```
context.Clients.User(userName).RecieveNotification(totalNewMessages);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because you are broadcasting to everyone. You haven't specified a specific connection. Check the following for info on how to specify a particular client/group. 
[Selecting which clients will receive the RPC](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server#selectingclients)